# ASP Response.Status not set correctly

Tags: iis, asp-classic, http-headers

I'm using Classic ASP and need to redirect a URL with a status code of 301. Here is the code I am using:

```
response.clear
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.frickingnutz.com"
Response.redirect ( "http://www.frickingnutz.com" )
response.end
```

However, when I use one of the many 'header' checking sites, I discover that IIS is returning a 302 status code:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved => 
Server => Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Date => Mon, 24 Jan 2011 14:20:08 GMT
X-Powered-By => ASP.NET
Location => http://www.frickingnutz.com
Connection => Keep-Alive
Content-Length => 148
Content-Type => text/html; Charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie => ASPSESSIONIDACCTDCSS=NLPNLBHCFEBAPMPODJPMDNMB; path=/
Cache-control => private
```

In fact I can't force any status code at all, I tried various different ones as a test, and all I can get is the 302.

I suspect it is some IIS setting but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..I just figured it out!

Didn't need the line

```
Response.redirect ( "http://www.frickingnutz.com" )
```

The *Location* header does that part. Doh!